# How to submit a form-control that can only be submitted using enter using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
var x = document.getElementById("chatMessage").value = 0;

chatMessage.value = '/send '+x+' '+y;
```

This is the code I am using to change the text in the form. It changed the text but the only way to submit the form on PC is by pressing enter. I want to be able to run a script that submits the form for me but I'm not entirely sure how I would get it to do this. 
I have tried submitting link below:

```
document.getElementById("chatMessage").submit();

document.getElementById("chatMessage").post();

document.getElementById("chatMessage").get();
```

The code for the form is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..."id="chatMessage" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off">
```

I can't edit the HTML code.

Comment: that's the HTML for the input ... show the HTML for the form ... you can't "submit" on an imput element, you can submit on a form element

Comment: for some reason when i do this it refreshes the page so the form doesn't properly submit

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to submit the input element parent form control:

```
document.getElementById("chatMessage").form.submit();
```

Comment: this causes the page to refresh and doesnt submit

Comment: @j_mason555 the refresh means it does submit, you simply don't handle it properly.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean when i submit it with enter it doesnt refresh sorry if this is something obvious but im farely new to coding

Comment: So it means you do something with JS, not submitting the form when Enter is pressed. You didn't give any useful code, so we really can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jquery or some other library at your disposal? If so you could just create a function that does something like:

```
$.post('form.php', { 
    chatMessage: $('#chatMessage').val()
});
```

Comment: the page is php but the form isnt over a whole page it is a chat defined as a form i think.

Answer (score 0):

If your form id is `myform` then you can submit it using

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

OR

If your form don't have an ID then you can submit it using form name.

*suppose form name is `myform`*

`document.myform.submit()`

Comment: it has an id but when i did this it says submit is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keycode :

```
function CallSent(e)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("chatMessage").value = 0;

    chatMessage.value = '/send '+x+' '+y;
var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
if(unicode==13)
{   
 document.x.submit();
}

}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..."id="chatMessage" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" onKeyPress="CallSent(Event)">
```

Comment: does this simulate an enter key press or detect an enter key press

Comment: when you press enter its automatically submit